# Possible Reason for the "NASA UFO sighting: Alien ship 25 TIMES size of Earth spotted near the Sun" news (does it fake or ...?)

Tags: the-sun

I have [this](https://www.express.co.uk/news/weird/1306231/nasa-ufo-sighting-alien-hollow-sun-theory-scott-waring-aliens-news) news:

[NASA UFO sighting: Alien ship 25 TIMES size of Earth spotted near the Sun](https://www.express.co.uk/news/weird/1306231/nasa-ufo-sighting-alien-hollow-sun-theory-scott-waring-aliens-news)

and tried to find the NASA site link by this [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=ufo%20sun%20%20site:nasa.gov&sxsrf=ALeKk00jJcmD3_s__cRGTKxqwqQR1o4vMg:1595884660946&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:y&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjrsMXSre7qAhXHzaQKHeKLB8UQpwV6BAgzEB8), but not found that news , so like to know what could be the reason of this situation, does it fake?

Thanks.

Comment: Fake would be my bet.

Comment: Questions about "flying objects" are not on topic for astronomy

Comment: **VtC Reviewers:** if you have a Sceptics SE account with a convincing rep, please consider suggesting a migration to this site in a flag.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because flying objects are usually off-topic, unless they contain a telescope.

Comment: It's quite clear that the "cube" in question is an image-processing artifact

Answer (score 6):

The Express is notorious for low-quality "science" stories.
In this case, someone who wanted to see a UFO looked at images from the [Solar and Heliospheric Observatory](https://sohowww.nascom.nasa.gov/) until he found a feature he could say something sensational about.
One might as well say, "I like turtles, that cloud looks like a turtle, therefore turtles come from the sky."
The mention of hollow sun "theory" is another red flag.

SOHO and its successor the [Solar Dynamics Observatory](https://sdo.gsfc.nasa.gov/) have recorded many legitimate phenomena including [coronal mass ejections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronal_mass_ejection) and [Sun-grazing comets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sungrazing_comet).

Comment: Some believe the universe is turtles all the way down.